# Avoid the contents of a .tar begin with './'

Tags: filenames, tar, archive

I want to make a backup of a directory using tar and xz, but I have a problem. When I open the file, all the files and directories begin with `./` and I don't want this to happen.

```
file.tar.xz
    |---- ./directory
        |---- ./file1.txt
    |---- ./file2.txt        
    |---- ./file3.txt
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
tar -cf - -C $dir --absolute-names . | xz -c > $output/$name.$date.txz
```

What I need to change to avoid this?

Comment: If you want to back up `/path/to/location`, then: `cd /path/to; tar zcf /path/to/archives/${name}.${date}.tgz location` should do the trick.

Comment: Avoid this in favor of what? Absolute names? Relative names without `./`?

Comment: Out of curiosity,  why is this a problem?  When extracted,  the dot will not be.  It will be treated as the current directory.  Incidentally, I think file1.txt would be `./directory/file1.txt`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind not handling files or directories with special characters in their names one level down from `$dir`:

```
tar -cf - -C "$dir" --absolute-names $(ls -A "$dir") | xz -c > "$output/$name.$date.txz"
```

This lists the contents of `$dir` and tells `tar` to archive that instead of `.`, which results in the contents of `$dir` appearing at the root of the archive.

Since you're not starting from a `/`-rooted path you don't need the GNU-specific `--absolute-names`:

```
tar -cf - -C "$dir" $(ls -A "$dir") | xz -c > "$output/$name.$date.txz"
```

Comment: You are using vendor specific options that only work in `gtar` but not in `tar`.

Comment: @shily the vendor option was reproduced from the question. It's safe to remove it though, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I have no problem with vendor specific extensions as long as they are clearly marked as such. If the examples e.g. used `gtar` as program name instead of `tar`, I of course did not send my comment.

Comment: The problem with that is that, for most users, `gtar` doesn't exist as a command, so the only general solution is to qualify vendor extensions in the surrounding text.

Comment: On all platforms I am aware of - except for a single platform (Linux) `gtar` is installed under it's native name `gtar`. The fact that Linux does not even provide a link to the native name of course causes confusion.

Comment: @schiy I believe your insistence on `gtar` is misplaced in several ways. Firstly, it's not universal. I just tried `gtar` on Mac OS; it was not found. However `gnutar` exists. Secondly, if you're scripting for utmost portability, you use `tar`, without any GNU options. If you're *not* scripting for portability, you can still use `tar`, and assume (or ensure) that PATH points to the GNU utilities over the scope of your script. Thirdly, the `g` doesn't generalize anyway. If I we to use the `-a` option of `cp`, there is no `gcp` or `gnucp`.

Comment: GNU utilities aren't really vendor extensions, because they are free and "everyone" has them. GNU tar is the same thing (modulo version) from every vendor that provides GNU tar on their system. Because it is ubiquitous, its options are not "vendor options" in the same sense as, say, some extension only found in the DG/UX version of grep.

Answer (score 3):

Using `pax` (the POSIX command for archiving):

```
(cd -P -- "$dir" && pax -w's|^\./||' .) | xz > file.tar.xz
```

However note that, like GNU `tar`'s `--transform`, the `s|^\./||` substitution is also applied to symlink targets, so if you have a `foo -> ./bar` symlink in the current directory, it will be archived as `foo -> bar`.

While with GNU `tar`, you can avoid it by passing the `S` flag:

```
tar --transform='s|^\./||S' -cf - . | xz > file.tar.xz
```

The standard `pax` command has no equivalent.

Comment: If you mention `pax` you would need to mention on which platforms it may be used safely. Note that `pax` on a typical Linux distro is full of bugs and thus should be avoided.

Comment: @schily, please add references to the corresponding bug reports if you think they may be relevant to this Q&A. On Debian and derivatives, `pax` is a port of MirBSD pax, so I expect those _bugs_ (assuming that's the implementation you're referring to) to also affect some BSDs. Also note that all software have bugs and bugs generally end up being fixed once they are reported, so it's important to refer to a version when mentioning a buggy implementation.

Comment: I refer to the GNU pax implementation (GNU paxutils) that is identical to GNU cpio. See  `star/README.otherbugs` for a list of problems.

Comment: @schily, what Linux distribution uses that? AFAIK, that implementation never went out of "alpha" status. I don't see any reference to GNU paxutils in schily-2015-12-16/star/README.otherbugs

Comment: GNU paxutils was shipped as gnucpio and this is mentioned. Things may have changed on Linux meanwhile, but a few years ago, it was a nightmare. Given that I do not use gtar or gcpio but rather `star`, I cannot tell when things might have changed.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, judging by the use of `--absolute-names`, you don't mind using GNU Tar options. In that case, the solution is simple, according to this pattern:

```
tar -cf archive.tar --transform s/..//S .
```

The `--transform` argument is a `sed` pattern which is applied to the each name before it is stored in the archive. Ours deletes the first two characters: the dot and slash. The `S` flag is to *not* do that substitution on the targets of symlinks.

If your directory doesn't contain hidden entries (those starting with `.`) that have to go into the archive, you can `cd` to the directory, where you can use the `*` pattern:

```
( cd "$dir" && tar -cf - -- * ) | xz -c > "$output/$name.$date.txz"
```

Note that we confine this directory change to a shell sub-process using parentheses. The right element of the pipeline, `xz ...`, executes in the original directory, so if `$output` is relative, it works as it should. We use `&&` so that we don't execute `tar` if the `cd` fails.

If there are a few `.` names, they can just be explicitly listed, as in `tar ... * .important1 .important2`.

Speaking of the `--absolute-names` GNU-specific option, I dropped that because its job is to retain a leading `/` from the paths (which would otherwise be stripped), which will not occur here.

For that to be meaningful, you have to do something like:

```
tar -cf whole-fs.tar --absolute-names /
tar -cf etc-dir.tar --absolute-names /etc
```

Comment: Your text does not apply to `tar`but only to `gtar` as you are using vendor specific options.

Comment: @schilly Do you have a suggested edit to the first sentence to make that even clearer?

Answer (score 0):

How about using the first free `tar` implementation `star` that by default strips a superfluous leading `./`?

Star is available at:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/s-tar/

and development snapshots are at:

http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/

Star was initially created in 1982 and for many years was part of all Linux distros. Then for unknown reason, most distros dropped it even though it includes Linux specific features that are missing in `gtar`or that have been inmplemented in a defective way on gtar. As far as I can tell many sysadmins fetch star and compile it because it causes less problems than other tar implementations.

The fact that star includes `libfind` since 2004 makes it possible to do things, you cannot do in a single step with other tar implementations ot you cannot do at all. A builtin in `find` makes many tasks much simpler.

Note that many features in other tar implementations first appeared in star and later have been included in other tar implementations. Most archive format extensions based on the POSIX.1-2001 standard that are currently in use in various tar implementations are taken from star.